# Как присваивать имя пользователю в web в зависимости от его имени пользователя в windows

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net-core

Учусь по примеру: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Как автоматически присваивать пользователю имя такое же как его имя в профиле windows? Например: учетная запись ylebedeva -> имя в вебе такое же ylebedeva

Comment: Никак, потому что иначе это была бы большая дыра в приватности пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что за учётка Windows.

Если например Active Directory, то можно при авторизации получать сведения оттуда. Если нет, то никак. На стороне браузера имя пользователя Windows определить нельзя, т.к. это запрещено политикой безопасности.

Comment: Как брать из AD имя пользователя?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс среды окружения Environment и его свойство Environment.UserName.